# Appium - unknown server side error - cannot launch app

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am getting this error when launching in the appium inspector

Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'za.co.xxx.app.debug' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n za.co.xxx.app.debug/io.gonative.android.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 255'; Command output: Exception occurred while executing 'start'

Here are my capabilities:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "appium:appPackage": "za.co.easyequities.app.debug",
  "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
  "appium:appActivity": "io.gonative.android.MainActivity",
  "appium:noReset": true
}
```

And this is the log:

```
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554","appium:appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554","appium:appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554","appium:appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554","appium:appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1711076547585 (11:02:27 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time))
[Appium] Attempting to find matching driver for automationName 'UiAutomator2' and platformName 'Android'
[Appium] The 'uiautomator2' driver was installed and matched caps.
[Appium] Will require it at C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver
[Appium] Requiring driver at C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\build\index.js
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Appium v2.5.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v3.0.4) session
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Checking BaseDriver versions for Appium and AndroidUiautomator2Driver
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Appium's BaseDriver version is 9.5.2
[AppiumDriver@db0c] AndroidUiautomator2Driver's BaseDriver version is 9.5.2
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]   "alwaysMatch": {
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "platformName": "Android",
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:appPackage": "za.co.easyequities.app.debug",
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:appActivity": "com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity",
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:noReset": true,
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages": true,
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:nativeWebScreenshot": true,
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:newCommandTimeout": 3600,
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     "appium:connectHardwareKeyboard": true
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]   },
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]   "firstMatch": [
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]     {}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]   ]
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4] }
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4] The following provided capabilities were not recognized by this driver:
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4]   connectHardwareKeyboard
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Session created with session id: c85b4c2a-95a7-4d36-abe4-8c8201d611e1
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find connected Android devices
[ADB] Getting connected devices
[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5554","state":"device"}]
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Starting 'za.co.easyequities.app.debug' directly on the device
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 31
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 12
[ADB] Device API level: 31
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Relaxing hidden api policy
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy 1''
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Pushing settings apk to the device...
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('5.7.7' >= '5.7.7')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys activity services io.appium.settings'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[Logcat] Starting logs capture with command: C:\\Users\\KlydeLencioco\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to local port 8200
[ADB] Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8200 tcp:6790'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v7.0.5.apk
[ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
[ADB] Using the previously cached signature entry for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[ADB] sha256 hash did match for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm path io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[ADB] Using the previously cached signature entry for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-v7.0.5.apk'
[ADB] sha256 hash did match for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-v7.0.5.apk'
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is greater or equal to the application version name ('7.0.5' >= '7.0.5')
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Server packages status: [{"wasSigned":true,"installState":"sameVersionInstalled","appPath":"C:\\Users\\KlydeLencioco\\.appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v7.0.5.apk","appId":"io.appium.uiautomator2.server"},{"wasSigned":true,"installState":"sameVersionInstalled","appPath":"C:\\Users\\KlydeLencioco\\.appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk","appId":"io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test"}]
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Server packages are not going to be (re)installed
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Waiting up to 30000ms for services to be available
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list instrumentation'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Instrumentation target 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' is available
[ADB] Adding packages ["io.appium.settings","io.appium.uiautomator2.server","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test"] to Doze whitelist
[ADB] Got the following command chunks to execute: [["dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.settings",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.uiautomator2.server",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test",";"]]
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.settings ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test ;'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] No obsolete sessions have been detected (socket hang up)
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Starting UIAutomator2 server 7.0.5
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Using UIAutomator2 server from 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v7.0.5.apk' and test from 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P","5037","-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","-e","disableAnalytics","true","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] socket hang up
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] socket hang up
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] socket hang up
[Instrumentation] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] socket hang up
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] socket hang up
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"None","value":{"message":"UiAutomator2 Server is ready to accept commands","ready":true}}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] The initialization of the instrumentation process took 5394ms
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","noReset":true,"ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"nativeWebScreenshot":true,"newCommandTimeout":3600,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true,"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","noReset":true,"ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"nativeWebScreenshot":true,"newCommandTimeout":3600,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"deviceUDID":"emulator-5554"}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05","value":{"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","noReset":true,"ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"nativeWebScreenshot":true,"newCommandTimeout":3600,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true,"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","appPackage":"za.co.easyequities.app.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","appActivity":"com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity","noReset":true,"ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"nativeWebScreenshot":true,"newCommandTimeout":3600,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"deviceUDID":"emulator-5554"}],"alwaysMatch":{}},"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05"}}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /appium/device/pixel_ratio] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05/appium/device/pixel_ratio] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/appium/device/system_bars' to command name 'getSystemBars'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /appium/device/system_bars] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05/appium/device/system_bars] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05/window/current/size] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [GET /appium/device/info] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05/appium/device/info] with no body
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys window'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05","value":3.5}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05","value":{"statusBar":84}}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05","value":{"height":3120,"width":1440}}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05","value":{"androidId":"4be4e8e09686d802","apiVersion":"31","bluetooth":{"state":"ON"},"brand":"google","carrierName":"T-Mobile","displayDensity":560,"locale":"en_US","manufacturer":"Google","model":"sdk_gphone64_x86_64","networks":[{"capabilities":{"SSID":null,"linkDownBandwidthKbps":30000,"linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":12000,"networkCapabilities":"NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED,NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED,NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN,NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING,NET_CAPABILITY_FOREGROUND,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_CONGESTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED","signalStrength":-50,"transportTypes":"TRANSPORT_WIFI"},"detailedState":"CONNECTED","extraInfo":"","isAvailable":true,"isConnected":true,"isFailover":false,"isRoaming":false,"state":"CONNECTED","subtype":-1,"subtypeName":"","type":1,"typeName":"WIFI"},{"capabilities":{"SSID":null,"linkDownBandwidthKbps":4300,"linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":1800,"networkCapabil...
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Starting 'za.co.easyequities.app.debug/com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity and waiting for 'za.co.easyequities.app.debug/com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'za.co.easyequities.app.debug' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)za\.co\.easyequities\.app\.debug\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n za.co.easyequities.app.debug/com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8ea0595e-ac2e-4ab6-af77-d1c0dabd7c05","value":null}
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys activity services io.appium.settings/.recorder.RecorderService'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp:8200'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@42f4 (c85b4c2a)] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''
[Instrumentation] .
[Instrumentation] Time: 4.119
[Instrumentation]
[Instrumentation] OK (1 test)
[Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 0
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1711076556329 (11:02:36 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time))
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'za.co.easyequities.app.debug' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\KlydeLencioco\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n za.co.easyequities.app.debug/com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 255'; Command output:
[AppiumDriver@db0c] Exception occurred while executing 'start':
[AppiumDriver@db0c] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=za.co.easyequities.app.debug/com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity } from null (pid=17715, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10147
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1047)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:975)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:665)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1441)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerService.java:2935)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:557)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:193)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:8609)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:950)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:834)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5106)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2498)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1184)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at ADB.startApp (C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:189:11)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.ensureAppStarts (C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:812:5)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.performSessionPostExecSetup (C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:635:7)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.startUiAutomator2Session (C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:683:5)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.createSession (C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\lib\driver.ts:405:22)
[AppiumDriver@db0c]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (C:\Users\KlydeLencioco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:717:35)
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 500 8755 ms - 5084
```

This only happens on my debug app but on our live app , I have no problem launching it. I hope someone can help me.